# Parity operator eigenstates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, parity

I have a problem I cannot solve on my own. I have given two states $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ and an Operator $O$ such that

$P \psi_1 = \epsilon_1 \psi_2$, $P \psi_2 = \epsilon_2 \psi_2$ and $POP^{-1} = \epsilon_3 P$ where $P$ is the parity operator and $\epsilon$ consists of the numbers -1 and +1. For which cases is $< \psi_1 | O | \psi_2 > = 0$?

Comment: Hi Darius and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: if $\epsilon_{1}\epsilon_{2}\epsilon_{3}$=-1 then $<\psi_{1}|O|\psi_{2}>=0$.

Comment: and why? how ca I show that?

Answer (score 1):

The situation is impossible and therefore doesn't happen.

When you claim to have two states $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ then I'll assume they are linearly independent, otherwise they aren't really two different states. Then you claim you have an Operator $O$ such that  $POP^{-1} = \epsilon_3 P$ where $P$ is the parity operator and further that $P \psi_1 = \epsilon_1 \psi_2$ and $P \psi_2 = \epsilon_2 \psi_2.$ and that $\epsilon$ consists of the numbers -1 and +1.

But if $P \psi_1 = \epsilon_1 \psi_2$ then $P (\epsilon_1\psi_1)= \epsilon_1^2 \psi_2=\psi_2$ and similarly if $P \psi_2 = \epsilon_2 \psi_2$ then $P (\epsilon_2\psi_2)= \epsilon_2^2 \psi_2=\psi_2.$ So we have two distinct vectors mapping to the same vector.

Which means $P (\epsilon_1\psi_1-\epsilon_2\psi_2)= 0.$ Which means there can't be a $P^{-1}$ since $$\begin{align}0&=P^{-1}(0)\\&=P^{-1}(P (\epsilon_1\psi_1-\epsilon_2\psi_2))\\&=\epsilon_1\psi_1-\epsilon_2\psi_2,\end{align}$$ but $0\neq\epsilon_1\psi_1-\epsilon_2\psi_2,$ since the states are linearly independent and the $\epsilon$ consists of the numbers -1 and +1.

So there are no cases where you have two states, some $\epsilon$ and an $O$ and a $P$ that satisfy your assumptions.